# SQL: what's an efficient way to turn data of money type into data with dollar format?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008, how can I display data stored as `varchar(25)` as money?

Sample data sets:

```
36839.20000
4560.00000
```

Desired data:

```
$36,839.20
$4,560.00
```

What SQL statement can help us to achieve the above?  Thanks.

Comment: Formatting should be done in the front end.

Comment: Title of the question and the content conflict, money to varchar or varchar to money with formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Use format if it is sql server 2012 and above

```
declare @cur numeric(10,2) = 8.28

select format(@cur, 'C', 'en-us') as USCurrency
```

Comment: Doesn't work for 2008. This is only available for 2012 onward. OP stated 2008 R2 was the environment. I actually posted the same answer and deleted it noticing this.

Comment: Please tag question to sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0):

Please check [CONVERT()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function

For your case, you may use the following code,

```
SELECT '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),amt,1) 
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: Data is stored as varchar(25) already, the conversion was to money type.

Comment: I think you meant this... `SELECT '$' + CONVERT(varchar, CAST('36839.20000' AS money), 1)`

Comment: The original post was saying that the current type is money, and he want convert to varchar with this format, not sure why it's gone

Comment: You are right, it was confusing... stated it was varchar and money.

Comment: @EricZ, you are right, why someone edited my OP?  It's not ethical.